# Replace line in .plist file to modify <string> - is it possible?

Tags: xml, macos, unix, plist

Basically I want to know if it's possible to create a script to edit an entry in a .plist file. However I don't want to replace a specific string, but the entire line so a new string can be added as the property will keep changing. An example:

```
<string>Something</string>
<key>SomethingElse</key>
<string>Numbers</string>
<key>Entry</key>
```

And having the third line changed to something like the following, regardless of what that line currently says.

```
<string>randomstuffhere</string>
```

I've been looking for a couple of hours and I think it's probably possible using sed but after looking at examples I can't seem to decipher it to construct it myself. Any and all help is appreciated. Oh, and I'd like to avoid using perl if possible.

EDIT: When using the following, the changes are made in the Terminal window but it doesn't seem to save it to the file. Using -i is apparently the way to fix this but it throws an error for me, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
sed -n '/SomethingElse/{p;n;s/>.*</>randomstuffhere</;};p' my.plist
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably easiest to use `defaults` to edit it:

```
defaults write /abs/path/to/plist SomethingElse "randomstuffhere"
```

Note that you *must* supply the absolute path to the plist file, and leave the ".plist" off of its filename.

Also (as pointed out in the comments) this tends to convert the plist file to the binary plist format variant; programs that use appropriate .plist reading frameworks will read this fine, but it'll no longer be human-readable. If you want it to be in the XML format variant, you can convert it with `plutil -convert xml1 /path/to/plist.plist`.

Alternately, you can use `PlistBuddy` instead of `defaults`:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :SomethingElse 'randomstuffhere'" /path/to/plist.plist
```

Comment: I thought about this too, however when I do what's shown above it seems to break the file and it becomes a mess of characters when I look inside it

Comment: `defaults` habitually converts .plist files to binary format, which looks weird but should work fine. If you want, you can convert it back with `plutil -convert xml1 /path/to/plist.plist`, or you could use PlistBuddy instead, since it doesn't have the same obsession with converting to binary: `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set : SomethingElse 'randomstuffhere'" /path/to/plist.plist`

Comment: Ah, defaults did work properly then. When I tried the PlistBuddy method however I got "Cannot Perform Set On Containers".

Comment: I somehow got a stray space in the PlistBuddy command; it should've been `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :SomethingElse 'randomstuffhere'" /path/to/plist.plist`

Comment: @GordonDavisson With your help, this PlistBuddy technique helps me create a tamper-proof HTML folder for my Cocoa app that uses a WebKit widget. I can generate a salted SHA512 hash, store this at compile time with a compile script that updates the Info.plist, and then on application boot, generate and compare hashes. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

So it's the third line you want to change?

```
 sed -i"" '3{;s\:.*:<string>randomstuffhere</string>:;}' .plist
```

I think osx `sed` supports the `-i` option, but you have to tell it to NOT use an backup extension to have it overwrite. Some sed's require that the initial char for the s///, if not a '/', should be esacped, ie `\:`. You may only need `:`.

I would test this as `sed '3{....}' file > newFile` before risking contents of a file. And to test `-i""`, work on a copy.

If you're looking to always change the line that has Numbers in it, then use

```
sed -i"" '\:<string>Numbers.*$:/<string>randomstuffhere</string>:` .plist
```

IHTH.

Comment: This returns with "sed: -i may not be used with stdin". Any alternatives?

Comment: how are you using `sed -i`, as illustrated in my answer? Try `man sed` to see if they have an illustration of the correct use of `sed -i` on osx. Else, use `sed '3{...}' file > newFile && mv newFile file`. Good luck.

Comment: I used sed -i as you explain, yes. It just doesn't appear to function on osx in the same way.